# Rails3/ActiveRecord: Change existing query to group by months

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, postgresql, activerecord

model entry.rb

```
def self.calculate(year, month, id)
     where(':id = entries.user_id', {    
          :id => id
     }).
     where('entries.date <= :last_day', { 
          :last_day => Date.new(year, month, 1).at_end_of_month
     }).
     select('sum(case when joint = "f" then amount_calc else 0 end) as sum_single,' + 
            'sum(case when joint = "t" then amount_calc else 0 end) as sum_joint,' + 
            'sum(case when compensation = "t" then amount_calc else 0 end) as sum_compensation')
  end
```

The query delivers three sums for a particular user and all entries up to the given month. Works fine so far.

What I really would need next is exactly the same but with one value for each month (and months in different years have to be in a different group). **The code needs to work with both SQLite and PostgreSQL.**

{ Additional question: is it possible to get the grouping and the overall sums like in my original code above in ONE query? I believe it is not possible... }

Comment: I think there are different syntax for Date functions in sqlite and postgre so you can't wrap it in one query. You should check for adapter first

Comment: I really hoped there was one solution for both databases. How do you switch the queries depending on the adapter in the model?

Comment: You can try this `ActiveRecord::Base.configurations[Rails.env]['adapter']`

Comment: There can't be one solution if the syntax is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite

```
def self.calculate(year, month, id)
 where(':id = entries.user_id', {    
      :id => id
 }).
 where('entries.date <= :last_day', { 
      :last_day => Date.new(year, month, 1).at_end_of_month
 }).
 select('sum(case when joint = "f" then amount_calc else 0 end) as sum_single,' + 
        'sum(case when joint = "t" then amount_calc else 0 end) as sum_joint,' + 
        'sum(case when compensation = "t" then amount_calc else 0 end) as sum_compensation').
 group("strftime('%Y-%m', created_at)")
end
```

Postgre something like this (I've never used this db)

```
def self.calculate(year, month, id)
 where(':id = entries.user_id', {    
      :id => id
 }).
 where('entries.date <= :last_day', { 
      :last_day => Date.new(year, month, 1).at_end_of_month
 }).
 select('sum(case when joint = "f" then amount_calc else 0 end) as sum_single,' + 
        'sum(case when joint = "t" then amount_calc else 0 end) as sum_joint,' + 
        'sum(case when compensation = "t" then amount_calc else 0 end) as sum_compensation').
 group("EXTRACT(YEAR FROM TIMESTAMP created_at)||EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP created_at)")
end
```

So you should firstly check what adapter is used and then use one of those queries